# nextAll().remove() not working with dynamic added element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here in my code i uses the jquery to load data from database with n-level performance .
But when i change the parent dropdown all next elements not going to remove please help.
Thank you in advance

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#subcat', function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $(this).nextAll('.remove').remove();
        var options = "<option value=0>--select subcategory--</option>";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/category/' + id + '/dropDownDynamic',
            success: function(responseText) {
                if (responseText != "") {
                    $.each(responseText, function(index, value) {
                        options += '<option value=' + index + '>' + value + '</option>'
                    });
                    $('#subcatCustom').append('<div class="form-group marginRemove remove"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select SubCategory:</label><div class="controls col-sm-5"><select name="parent" id="subcat" class="form-control">' + options + '</select></div></div>');
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

this line not working.

```
$(this).nextAll('.remove').remove();
```

Comment: Also add `HTML` in the question

Comment: please post your HTMl also

Comment: @Sandeeproop Tushar already asked for that

Comment: respect of your response but its solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are not sibling of the current `subcat` element, they are siblings of current `.remove` so try

```
$(this).closest('.remove').nextAll('.remove').remove();
```

In your event handler `this` refers to the `#subcat` element, which is a descendant of `.remove` element, so we uses [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `.remove` ancestor of `this`, then find that ancestor's next siblings

Note: ID of an element must be unique, so use `subcat` as a class instead of ID.